# Angular pipes binding

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I'd like to dynamically bind the pipe used in a template. I understand that the same result can be achieved by doing `this.myPipe.transform(...)` but I wonder if it's possible to do something like:

```
import { DecimalPipe, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class MyClass {

  value=1593452569489;
  myPipe;

  constructor(private numberPipe:DecimalPipe, private datePipe:DatePipe) { }

  viewAsNumber() {
    this.myPipe = numberPipe;
  }

  viewAsDate() {
    this.myPipe = datePipe;
  }

  ...
}
```

and then on the template:

```
{{ value |  myPipe }}
```

Comment: Did you register your pipe in main or feature module? there you can register, and use it

Comment: I'm seeing this error: ```The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found ("{{[ERROR ->]value |  myPipe}}```.

Comment: Do I need to register DecimalPipe and DatePipe? do I also need to register ```myPipe``` and how to go about it?

Comment: it seems `myPipe` is not assigned. When the function `viewAsNumber` is called? Did you try to use directly  `numberPipe` instead of myPipe?

Comment: Same error... ```ERROR in The pipe 'numberPipe' could not be found ("{{[ERROR ->]value |  numberPipe}}```

Comment: you don't define pipes in the typescript. you would do something like `{{value | datePipe}}` and inside the pipe you have it defined as `@Pipe({name: 'datePipe'})`. From there it just needs to be included in your module

Comment: But how do I make the datePipe here ```{{value | datePipe}}``` change to numberPipe?